Easing functions for using CADisplayLink
I need to manually animate something frame by frame in SwiftUI using CADisplayLink, which provides me frame to frame updates. For animating a value from a to b in a linear fashion, the implementation is trivial, simply calculate a rate of change with (b-a) / duration and apply this delta to the value on every frame.
However, I'm not finding any information on how to do frame to frame updates when the animation isn't linear. I can, of course, create the easing functions myself using say, for example, the numeric package, but it seems too common of a use case for needing so much manual implementation.
Where are the out-of-the-box easing functions from Apple? There should be a package of easing functions that allows me to retrieve y using x, yet this post suggests that there aren't any?

You're correct that if you're going to use CADisplayLink it is up to you, every time you are called back, to decide, based on the elapsed time, how much adjustment to make in whatever it is you are animating. There is no "package of easing functions", though it is certainly possible to imitate the built-in simple timing functions because Apple gives you the control points of their Bezier curves. But if you wanted all this to happen without work on your part, you would use the built-in animation stuff, not CADisplayLink.

If you can use SwiftUI and have a minimum deployment version of iOS 17, you can use UnitCurve.

A function defined by a two-dimensional curve that maps an input progress in the range [0,1] to an output progress that is also in the range [0,1]. By changing the shape of the curve, the effective speed of an animation or other interpolation can be changed.

You can pass in a progress, which is the percentage of the animation that's elapsed, then get a new progress value to use when calculating the current state of the value being animated.
let newProgress = UnitCurve.easeInOut.value(at: progress)
let newValue = a + (b - a) * newProgress


If you need some other animation curves, https://easings.net/ is a good reference for commonly used curves. It also includes the math to produce the curve at the bottom of each page.

This is basically what I said in my comment; I'm glad that it's so nicely packaged in iOE 17, though!

Oh great. Thank you this is exactly what I needed
